# How to evaluate the hilliness of an area using SRTM data?

Tags: raster, srtm

I want to evaluate the hilliness of an area (e.g. municipality) using SRTM data. I thought about just calculating the standard deviation of the raster cells but my gut feeling is that this approach might be to simplistic.
What is the best approach to measure/evaluate the hilliness of a region using raster data?

Comment: "Hilliness" sounds quite subjective - how would you describe "hilliness"? Does it have to have peaks, or is one big slope across the area a hill? Do the peaks have to be a certain size range? Or a certain height range? Can you add some examples of elevation maps that are hilly and not hilly?

Comment: Some possible ideas here: https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/jess/122/03/0869-0886 - where have you researched so far?

Comment: What GIS software are you using? Try ruggedness index, for example in QGIS: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_analysis/triterrainruggednessindex.html